# Magento 2.1.5 Server load very high suddenly

Tags: magento2.1.5

I have a magento 2.1.5 EE website. There are around 5000 visitors a day.  Below are the server Specifications:

- Intel Xeon E3-1270 CPU
- 3.50Ghz CPU Clock Speed
- 4 CPU Cores
- 8 CPU Threads
- 8MB CPU Cache
- 16GB DDR3 RAM
- 1TB SATA II HDD
- 5TB Bandwidth

I am facing a problem recently. I installed an extension ,after two days I disabled it and then I enabled it after 1 day. After enabling the extension, I run the setup:upgrade command. The command takes a lot of time which is unusual and the Server load reaches 30.

I tried to figure out the problem:

- Disabled the cron jobs
- Uninstalled the above extension
- run the setup upgrade and the di:compile and the deploy commmands
- Cleared the cache

The Server load is increasing quickly to reach 30 for a little time then it decreases back to 1-2. This is happening multiple times a day.

I contacted the hosting company, they said that the resources usage is not related to the traffic I am getting, but rather to the number of executions my website scripts are making.

I wonder how can I solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Varnish or the built-in FPC?  With Varnish it should be very fast. But it could be your extension has some flaw driving up load, or long/infinite loop.

Remove the extension and test without it to confirm.

You can also try the built-in M2 profiler to see if there are long/excessive amounts of calls at your hosting company indicates. Or tools like xdebug/strace etc.

Comment: I am using the Varnish Cache. 

I have disabled and deleted the extension but the problem still exists. Does a disabled extension still affects the wesbite?  I am going to install xdebug to check the issue.

Comment: It could affect it, you might also have to confirm its disabled with magento module:status (I think thats the right one).  And delete everything in var like di and generate then redeploy production mode and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's what I did exactly. I deleted the di and generate directories then I redeployed production. 

I was viewing recent emails received from a cron job I created on the server to monitor the server load, I find 5 emails reporting that the website is down. The emails are received an hour after creating campaigns on the website. so would it be a high traffic issue?